# Can we call external web service from SharePoint workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, web-services, office-365

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow which needs to call a web service outside of SharePoint. The web service is hosted in some server say "http://www.abc.com/Service.svc".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow has new "**Call HTTP Web Service**" action using which you can call HTTP (REST) web service.

See this Blog on [Calling Web service in designer workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/05/how-to-work-with-web-service-using-call-http-web-service-action.aspx).